# How to push values in a particular order to a map

Tags: groovy

I am using cassandra database and I am storing the values like this:

```
id         language              code                 text
1           E                    001                  Read
2           D                    002                  Schreiben
3           E                    002                  Writing
4           D                    001                  Lesen
```

I want the values to be added to a map in a particular order as follows:

```
data=[001:[Read, Lesen], 002:[Writing, Schreiben]]
```

In the println I see the results as `data=[001:[Read, Lesen],002:[Schreiben, Writing]]`. How do I add the values in the same order: First E, then D?

Comment: Use an ordered map, like `LinkedHashMap`. `HashMap` doesn't preserve insertion order. `Map<String, ArrayList<String>> res = [:]` should sort you out

Comment: @ernest_k In the map i see the values the way it is stored in database.

Comment: it's not the `Map` that does not preserve the order. You should sort your records (by id) when you pull them from the databse

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pasted your cassandra/CQL schema, but it's likely this is going to happen for you for free by default.

The way Cassandra encodes data into the storage engine will naturally sort the keys in ascending order using whatever type is defined in the `map<keyType,valType>` definition.

That said, once you read it out of the database, your application may try to transform it from its natural order into a map/dict object in your language of choice, which may remove the ordering in favor of hashing.

Comment: As you said cassandra will sort the keys.But from the application level it changes the order because of hashing.So how to change it so that values can be saved only in this order[E,D] in a map?

Comment: Use a map that preserves order, like a java TreeMap instead of a HashMap.